# API Google Speech to Text - mp3 file

Tags: google-speech-api

I was able to transcribe an audio using the tutorial contained in the link (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize), but it only works with audio in WAV format. I would like to make it work with audio in MP3 or M4A format.

I've already tested all the possibilities contained in the link (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/speech/Recognize. java) and follow the guidelines in the link (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding)

On the Google Cloud home page, the Speech API demo tool lets you send an mp3 file and the transcript takes place.

I would like a community help for my request to transcribe an audio with more than 1 minute in mp3 format.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help. But let me explain it in a different way.

On the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/speech/Recognize.java) page, ways to use an audio file to do the transcription. However, in all possibilities presented in GitHub, none of them could transcribe an audio in a format other than WAV. Most of my files are in MP3 and M4A.

I always get the following answer:

`Exception in thread" main "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
at java.util.Collections $ EmptyList.get (Collections.java:4454)
at com.logusit.speech.speech.SpeechApplication.main (SpeechApplication.java:50)`

I believe the problem is in the RecognitionConfig in the setEncoding and setSampleRateHertz parameters. I can not find the correct JAVA setting to transcribe a file other than WAV.